# Rails: Refile for documents to download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refile

Using the `refile` gem, I have uploaded documents (.pdf, .docx, .pptx, etc.). Uploading is fine. When I use `attachemnt_url`, it produces something like `/attachments/...234jksdf2.../document`. When I click the `link_to`, it downloads the document without an extension.

What's happening to make it operate this way? How can I restore my file type sanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up being the correct solution for me.

`link_to "Download file", attachment_url(@document, :file, format: @document.file_extension)`

```
def file_extension 
    require 'rack/mime'   
    Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[document_content_type].split('.').last 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to address the exact same issue, this is one approach I tried:

Refile allows you to save additional metadata such as the `content_type`: https://github.com/refile/refile#additional-metadata. The resulting file content type will be saved as something like `"image/png"` or `"application/pdf"`.

We can then apply something like

```
link_to "Download file", attachment_url(@document, :file, format: @document.file_extension)
```

Whereby

```
in document.rb

def file_extension
    file_content_type.split("/").last.to_sym
end
```

The only issue is that this doesn't automatically downloads the file, but rather opens it in a new page where you can then download the file. Still looking for better alternatives!

Comment: I'll try asap tomorrow. Please update if you find a solution!

Comment: This is closer, but I'm getting a pretty odd url out of the `attachment_url`.

Comment: What's the url and what is returned exactly?

Comment: Something that looks like this: `http://host.com/attachments/a8ea1c0e1212b9fe11c230ab3d0ce9110e689706/store/application/vnd.ms-excel/0e76b0554c33275d7f48030226a28f9a2d56bee2e930c4cf5af8a032497f/file-name.xls`, but I get (what looks like nginx) `not found` error.

Comment: This is ok for images, but if it's a macroenabled excel file, I don't get .xls, I get `vnd.ms-excel`, so this won't work.

Comment: This is what I had to implement to get things to work:  

`def file_extension
    require 'rack/mime'
    Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[document_content_type].split('.').last
  end`